# How to return a value when a class instance is referenced in c++

Tags: c++

Is it possible to return a value when referencing (not sure it's the correct term) an instance of a class?
For example:

```cpp
class A {

};

int main() {
    A instance;
    int val = instance; // how can I make this return a int for example?
}
```

I'm pretty sure this is possible as it works with `std::string`:

```cpp
std::string s = "ABC";
std::cout << s; // prints 'ABC'.
```

Comment: `std::string` doesn't do this. It overloads `operator<<`, so output works, but you won't have much luck in other scenarios like `const char* x = s;`

Comment: Note: your `std::string` example does the opposite of what you ask about - it converts `const char[]` to `std::string` object. This is done with constructors. You want the opposite conversion - from class to `int`. This is done with conversion operators.